# How to preserve the namespaces while transforming an XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an input XML to strip off unwanted nodes and at the same time to preserve the namespace references on all the nodes where they are already existing. I've framed my XSL to do so, but I'm not sure why isn't preserving the namespaces on the Output XML. Here are the input XML, XSL used to transform and the outuput XML.

Input XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <FullOrderResponse xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata" preserveSpace="no"
        qAccess="0">
        <record xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
            <oldRecord>
                <FullOrder xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
                    <Header>
                        <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
                        <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
                        <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
                        <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.0</OrderDate>
                        <RequiredDate>1996-08-01T00:00:00.0</RequiredDate>
                        <ShippedDate>1996-07-16T00:00:00.0</ShippedDate>
                        <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
                        <Freight>32.38</Freight>
                        <ShipName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</ShipName>
                        <ShipAddress>59 rue de l'Abbaye</ShipAddress>
                        <ShipCity>Reims</ShipCity>
                        <ShipRegion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            null="true" xsi:nil="true" />
                        <ShipPostalCode>51100</ShipPostalCode>
                        <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
                    </Header>
                    <Lines>
                        <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
                        <ProductID>11</ProductID>
                        <UnitPrice>14</UnitPrice>
                        <Quantity>12</Quantity>
                        <Discount>0</Discount>
                    </Lines>
                    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
                </FullOrder>
            </oldRecord>
        </record>
    </FullOrderResponse>
</data>
```

Output XML (which is required / desired) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <FullOrderResponse xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata" preserveSpace="no"
        qAccess="0">
        <record xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
            <oldRecord>
                <FullOrder xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
                    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
                    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
                    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
                    <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
                    <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.0</OrderDate>
                    <RequiredDate>1996-08-01T00:00:00.0</RequiredDate>
                    <ShippedDate>1996-07-16T00:00:00.0</ShippedDate>
                    <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
                    <Freight>32.3800</Freight>
                    <ShipName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</ShipName>
                    <ShipAddress>59 rue de l'Abbaye</ShipAddress>
                    <ShipCity>Reims</ShipCity>
                    <ShipRegion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        null="true" xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ShipPostalCode>51100</ShipPostalCode>
                    <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
                    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
                    <ProductID>11</ProductID>
                    <UnitPrice>14.0000</UnitPrice>
                    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
                    <Discount>0.0</Discount>
                </FullOrder>
            </oldRecord>
        </record>
    </FullOrderResponse>
</data>
```

I've tried to use the solution that was provided in the following question asked on SO, but I'm not sure if it works for my situation. Reference to the old question already asked on this topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147876/how-to-preserve-xml-namespace-in-xslt-output). Any help / hints / suggestions on this is much appreciated

XSL that I framed to achieve the desired output XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:nw="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:variable name="vNamespace"
        select="document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='nw']" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tuple/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$vNamespace" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nw:Header">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nw:Lines">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, all you need to do is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:nw="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nw:Header | nw:Lines">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. This:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="tuple/*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:copy-of select="$vNamespace" />
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

   does not match anything in your XML, and therefore is not applied.
   Nor is it necessary.
2. In your input, there is a redundant namespace declaration on the
   `record` element:

   ```
   <record xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">
   ```

   The parent element, `FullOrderResponse`, already declared the same
   namespace as the default namespace. Therefore you can expect the
   XSLT processor to strip the redundant declaration and let `record`
   inherit the default namespace declared by its parent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the usage of a redundant <xsl:template> @michael.hor257k, but just wondering - isn't it necessary to have that namespace included on the child nodes as well (reason for asking this is that, the namespace is included in the request XML - which in turn is a webservice response)?

Comment: @BPavanKumar A default namespace (one that is declared without binding it to a prefix) is inherited by all descendant elements (unless explicitly overridden by a prefix). For example, in your input XML, the `oldRecord` element is in the same namespace as its parent `record`. Changing it to `<oldRecord xmlns="http://schemas.argility.com/NorthwindMetadata">` would not change anything.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, understood now! :)